# Real-Time geolocation ionic

Tags: leaflet, ionic-framework

I want to build mobile app with ionic, first the user is geolocated i want to update his position every 2 seconds this is the code for the geolocation

```
$scope.makeFit = function() {
  leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
    var marker;
    function onLocationFound(e) {
      marker= new L.Marker(e.latlng);
      marker.addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("" + e.latlng + " ");
    }
    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound); 
  });
};
```

Comment: Please clarify what you intend to ask.

Comment: I have a marker on my map representing the current location i'm trying to get it to move every 2 second to follow the location of the user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please [read the Leaflet reference documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate-options), which documents the `watch` option of `locate()`, that will do this.